# Android button layout - get two buttons side-by-side across entire screen

Tags: android, xml, button, android-linearlayout

I have two buttons which I would like to appear side-by-side horizontally, but together they fill the horizontal length of the phone. The height is wrap content, that's fine. My issue right now is that only one button is showing up (stretching across the screen).

Here is my XML code:

```
<LinearLayout 
   android:id="@+id/page_buttons"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:gravity="center_horizontal"

   >
   <Button
        android:id="@+id/prevButton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Previous"
   /> 

   <Button
        android:id="@+id/nextButton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Next"
   />
```

Comment: exactly how do you expect two buttons to appear on the screen, given that you've specified just one in the xml? Are you dynamically creating the second one and adding it to the linear layout?

Comment: I edited the post to make it readable now.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Change your Buttons XML to include the `layout_weight` attribute:

```
<Button android:id="@+id/nextButton"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Next"/>
```

Comment: In addition to the accepted answer, I think it is worth pointing out that the Linear Layout that wraps the two buttons should have the option `android:orientation="horizontal"`.
I'm slow and didn't catch this at first.

Answer (score 16):

Since nobody is explaining why their solutions work, I will give it a go.

The problem lies in the layout of the buttons. The two concerned attributes are layout_width and layout_weight.

In other layout systems, when you indicate that each element of a layout has to fill the parent (layout_width="fill_parent"), they do so by distributing equally the space of the parent between them. So, each of them would have the same size.

> Instead, in Android's layout system, if both elements have
>   layout_width="fill_parent" the first element (in your case, the
>   Previews button) will be stretched to fill the parent and the second
>   (or third, or etc.) will not have any space left to distribute, so it
>   will not be visible.

Now, to make it understand that you want both buttons to show, you set the layout_weight for each button. To make the buttons have the same size, set the same layout weight to both of them.

The layout_weight defines how many "parts" (or segments) of the parent each of the buttons occupy. The parent will be cut into a number of segments equal to the sum of the children's segments. If you want to make one button three times bigger then the other, you have to assign it the number of parts equal to the number of parts of the first button, multiplied by three.

> So if you want your Next button to be two times bigger then the
>   Previews button, you can do this:
>
> - for Previews button: layout_weight=1
> - for Next button: layout_weight=2

In consequence, the parent will be cut in 3 parts, 2 of which will be allocated to the Next button and 1 to the Previews button.

The example taken here is for buttons and horizontal layout, but this will work just fine for any type of object and also for vertical layout parent.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation

Answer (score 5):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<Button
  android:id="@+id/button01"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_below="@id/entry" 
  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
  android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/space"/>
<TextView
  android:id="@+id/space"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
<Button
  android:id="@+id/button02"
  android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button01"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_below="@id/entry" 
  android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>  
</RelativeLayout>
```

Seems like you want two equal buttons, not wrapped content. I created a centered spacer using TextView, and relatively aligned to that. Left button to parent left and spacer, Right button to Left Button and parent right.

Answer (score 1):

Parent of your Button is Linear-Layout, and you are setting Button's width as fill parent and hence it is taking the whole space. You hav two options to Implement this...

1. Give the fixed width for your button(eg 50dip).
2. Give the width as 0dp and insert one more attribute in both button "weight" and give 0.5dip for each...

Answer (score 1):

The two buttons should be on a linearlayout. The linear layout should be horizontal and each button has a weight of 1. This should give you two buttons with equal size along the screen width. A sample is here
[Horizontal orientation: check the 2 Buttons at the end of this xml  layout](http://harisankar-krishnaswamy.blogspot.in/2013/07/android-ui-activity-to-show-license.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your Requirement is

```
<LinearLayout 
   android:id="@+id/page_buttons"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"

   >
   <Button
        android:id="@+id/prevButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:weight="0.5"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Previous"
   /> 

   <Button
        android:id="@+id/nextButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:weight="0.5"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Next"
   />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"> 

    <TextView 
        android:text="@+id/SomeText" 
        android:id="@+id/TextView01" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" /> 

    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:background="@android:drawable/bottom_bar" 
        android:paddingLeft="4.0dip" 
        android:paddingTop="5.0dip" 
        android:paddingRight="4.0dip" 
        android:paddingBottom="1.0dip" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_below="@+id/TextView01"> 

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/allow" 
            android:layout_width="0.0dip" android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:text="Allow" 
            android:layout_weight="1.0" /> 

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/deny" 
            android:layout_width="0.0dip" android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:text="Deny" 
            android:layout_weight="1.0" /> 

    </LinearLayout> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the leading issue for people who still seems to not get what they want.
when using buttons with their conventional (out-of-the-box/default) background, it has a built in margin.
If you try changing the background manually with a single color, you can tell easily that you just need to set a separate background.
other than that when you have the weights put in, it will work.